# How can I get the text value of an li element in a treeview when clicking on any li element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
    $.fn.extend({
        treed: function (o) {

          var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
          var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

          if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
            if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
            openedClass = o.openedClass;
            }
            if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
            closedClass = o.closedClass;
            }
          };

            //initialize each of the top levels
            var tree = $(this);
            tree.addClass("tree");
            tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
                var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
                branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
                branch.addClass('branch');
                branch.on('click', function (e) {
                    if (this == e.target) {
                        var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                        icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
                        $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>");         
                          setTimeout(()=>{
                            $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                            $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                          }, 400)
                    }
                })
                branch.children().children().toggle();
            });
            //fire event from the dynamically added icon
          tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
            $(this).on('click', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
            });
          });
            //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
            tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
                $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                    $(this).closest('li').click();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
            //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
            tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
                $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                    $(this).closest('li').click();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        }
    });

    //Initialization of treeviews

    $('#tree1').treed();
$.fn.extend({
  treed: function (o) {

    var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
    var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

    if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
      if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
      openedClass = o.openedClass;
      }
      if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
      closedClass = o.closedClass;
      }
    };

//initialize each of the top levels
      var tree = $(this);
      tree.addClass("tree");
      tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
          var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
          branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
          branch.addClass('branch');

          // declare a flag to toggle
          let flag = false;
          branch.on('click', function (e) {
              if (this == e.target) {
                  // toggle on click
                  flag = !flag;
                  var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                  icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass); 

                  // show loader only when its opened, and collpase once toggled   
                  if(flag) {
                    $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>"); 
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                      $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                      $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                    }, 400)
                  } else {
                    $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                  }
              }
          })
          branch.children().children().toggle();
      });

//fire event from the dynamically added icon
    tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
      $(this).on('click', function () {
          $(this).closest('li').click();
      });
    });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
          });
      });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
              });
          });
      }
    });
    
    //Initialization of treeviews
    
    $('#tree1').treed();
    
    $('#tree2').treed({openedClass:'fa-folder-open', closedClass:'fa-folder'});
```

```css
    .tree, .tree ul {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      list-style:none;
      margin-left:10px;
    }
    .tree ul {
      margin-left:1em;
      position:relative
    }
    .tree ul ul {
      margin-left:.5em
    }
    .tree ul:before {
      content:"";
      display:block;
      width:0;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      border-left:1px solid
    }
    .tree li {
      margin:0;
      padding:0 1em;
      line-height:2em;
      color:#369;
      font-weight:700;
      position:relative;
    }
    .tree ul li:before {
      content:"";
      display:block;
      width:10px;
      height:0;
      border-top:1px solid;
      margin-top:-1px;
      position:absolute;
      top:1em;
      left:0
    }
    .tree ul li:last-child:before {
      background:#fff;
      height:auto;
      top:1em;
      bottom:0
    }
    .indicator {
      margin-right:5px;
    }
    .tree li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:#369;
    }
    .tree li button, .tree li button:active, .tree li button:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:#369;
      border:none;
      background:transparent;
      margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
      padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
      outline: 0;
    }

    .loading {
      font-style: italic;
    }
.timeline {
  border-left: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.timeline .timeline-item {
  position: relative;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  left: -38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  content: "";

}
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <ul id="tree2">
              <li>
                 <a href="#">TECH</a>
                 <ul>
                    <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                    <li>
                       Employees
                       <ul>
                          <li>
                             Reports
                             <ul>
                                <li>Report1 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label"> li text</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> </li>                            <li>Report2 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>                              <li>Report3 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                             </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Human Resources</li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                 XRP
                 <ul>
                    <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                    <li>
                       Employees
                       <ul>
                          <li>
                             Reports
                             <ul>
                                <li>Report1 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                                <li>Report2
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                                <li>Report3 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                             </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Human Resources</li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css">
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

I have a treeview with nested ul and li elements and I am trying to get the text value of the li elements when they are clicked. I need to retrieve these text values in a Bootstrap modal (you will find the modal with an input where the text value of the li element should be printed).
Note: You will find a button with the add icon next to each li element. Clicking on it will display the modal with an input where the text value of the li element should be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this could be solution for your problem

```
// On "plus" button click
$(document).on("click", ".tree li .btn-primary", function () {
    var text = $(this).closest("li").contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType === 3; }).text();

    $(".modal-body .form-control").val(text.trim());
});
```

Below is merged with code snippet

```js
$.fn.extend({
    treed: function (o) {
        var openedClass = "fa-minus-circle";
        var closedClass = "fa-plus-circle";

        if (typeof o != "undefined") {
            if (typeof o.openedClass != "undefined") {
                openedClass = o.openedClass;
            }
            if (typeof o.closedClass != "undefined") {
                closedClass = o.closedClass;
            }
        }

        //initialize each of the top levels
        var tree = $(this);
        tree.addClass("tree");
        tree.find("li")
            .has("ul")
            .each(function () {
                var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
                branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
                branch.addClass("branch");
                branch.on("click", function (e) {
                    if (this == e.target) {
                        var icon = $(this).children("i:first");
                        icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
                        $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>");
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            $(this).find(".loading").remove();
                            $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                        }, 400);
                    }
                });
                branch.children().children().toggle();
            });
        //fire event from the dynamically added icon
        tree.find(".branch .indicator").each(function () {
            $(this).on("click", function () {
                $(this).closest("li").click();
            });
        });
        //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
        tree.find(".branch>a").each(function () {
            $(this).on("click", function (e) {
                $(this).closest("li").click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
        tree.find(".branch>button").each(function () {
            $(this).on("click", function (e) {
                $(this).closest("li").click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    },
});

//Initialization of treeviews

$("#tree1").treed();
$.fn.extend({
    treed: function (o) {
        var openedClass = "fa-minus-circle";
        var closedClass = "fa-plus-circle";

        if (typeof o != "undefined") {
            if (typeof o.openedClass != "undefined") {
                openedClass = o.openedClass;
            }
            if (typeof o.closedClass != "undefined") {
                closedClass = o.closedClass;
            }
        }

        //initialize each of the top levels
        var tree = $(this);
        tree.addClass("tree");
        tree.find("li")
            .has("ul")
            .each(function () {
                var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
                branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
                branch.addClass("branch");

                // declare a flag to toggle
                let flag = false;
                branch.on("click", function (e) {
                    if (this == e.target) {
                        // toggle on click
                        flag = !flag;
                        var icon = $(this).children("i:first");
                        icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);

                        // show loader only when its opened, and collpase once toggled
                        if (flag) {
                            $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>");
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                $(this).find(".loading").remove();
                                $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                            }, 400);
                        } else {
                            $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                        }
                    }
                });
                branch.children().children().toggle();
            });

        //fire event from the dynamically added icon
        tree.find(".branch .indicator").each(function () {
            $(this).on("click", function () {
                $(this).closest("li").click();
            });
        });
        //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
        tree.find(".branch>a").each(function () {
            $(this).on("click", function (e) {
                $(this).closest("li").click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
        tree.find(".branch>button").each(function () {
            $(this).on("click", function (e) {
                $(this).closest("li").click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    },
});

//Initialization of treeviews

$("#tree1").treed();

$("#tree2").treed({ openedClass: "fa-folder-open", closedClass: "fa-folder" });

$(document).on("click", ".tree li .btn-primary", function () {
    var text = $(this).closest("li").contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType === 3; }).text();

    $(".modal-body .form-control").val(text.trim());
});
```

```css
.tree,
.tree ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.tree ul {
    margin-left: 1em;
    position: relative;
}
.tree ul ul {
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}
.tree ul:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid;
}
.tree li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    line-height: 2em;
    color: #369;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
}
.tree ul li:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    margin-top: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: 0;
}
.tree ul li:last-child:before {
    background: #fff;
    height: auto;
    top: 1em;
    bottom: 0;
}
.indicator {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.tree li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #369;
}
.tree li button,
.tree li button:active,
.tree li button:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #369;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    outline: 0;
}

.loading {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <ul id="tree2">
            <li>
                <a href="#">TECH</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                    <li>
                        Employees
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Reports
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        Report1
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h1>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        <form>
                                                            <div class="mb-3">
                                                                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label"> li text</label>
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Report2
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Report3
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Human Resources</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                XRP
                <ul>
                    <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                    <li>
                        Employees
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Reports
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        Report1
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Report2
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Report3
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Human Resources</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can I do the same thing with (ul) text values?

Comment: `UL` does not have text property, he is just a wrap for `LI` elements

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter element that your li is not with the class "branch"

`$('li:not(.branch)')` - https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

```js
$.fn.extend({
        treed: function (o) {

          var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
          var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

          if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
            if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
            openedClass = o.openedClass;
            }
            if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
            closedClass = o.closedClass;
            }
          };

            //initialize each of the top levels
            var tree = $(this);
            tree.addClass("tree");
            tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
                var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
                branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
                branch.addClass('branch');
                branch.on('click', function (e) {
                    if (this == e.target) {
                        var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                        icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
                        $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>");         
                          setTimeout(()=>{
                            $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                            $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                          }, 400)
                    }
                })
                branch.children().children().toggle();
            });
            //fire event from the dynamically added icon
          tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
            $(this).on('click', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
            });
          });
            //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
            tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
                $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                    $(this).closest('li').click();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
            //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
            tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
                $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                    $(this).closest('li').click();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        }
    });

    //Initialization of treeviews

    $('#tree1').treed();
$.fn.extend({
  treed: function (o) {

    var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
    var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

    if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
      if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
      openedClass = o.openedClass;
      }
      if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
      closedClass = o.closedClass;
      }
    };

//initialize each of the top levels
      var tree = $(this);
      tree.addClass("tree");
      tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
          var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
          branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
          branch.addClass('branch');

          // declare a flag to toggle
          let flag = false;
          branch.on('click', function (e) {
              if (this == e.target) {
                  // toggle on click
                  flag = !flag;
                  var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                  icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass); 

                  // show loader only when its opened, and collpase once toggled   
                  if(flag) {
                    $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>"); 
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                      $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                      $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                    }, 400)
                  } else {
                    $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                  }
              }
          })
          branch.children().children().toggle();
      });

//fire event from the dynamically added icon
    tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
      $(this).on('click', function () {
          $(this).closest('li').click();
      });
    });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
          });
      });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
              });
          });
      }
    });
    
    //Initialization of treeviews
    
    $('#tree1').treed();
    
    $('#tree2').treed({openedClass:'fa-folder-open', closedClass:'fa-folder'});
    
$('li:not(.branch)').on('click', function(e) {
  console.clear();
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.tree, .tree ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.tree ul {
  margin-left:1em;
  position:relative
}
.tree ul ul {
  margin-left:.5em
}
.tree ul:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  border-left:1px solid
}
.tree li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0 1em;
  line-height:2em;
  color:#369;
  font-weight:700;
  position:relative;
}
.tree ul li:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:10px;
  height:0;
  border-top:1px solid;
  margin-top:-1px;
  position:absolute;
  top:1em;
  left:0
}
.tree ul li:last-child:before {
  background:#fff;
  height:auto;
  top:1em;
  bottom:0
}
.indicator {
  margin-right:5px;
}
.tree li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#369;
}
.tree li button, .tree li button:active, .tree li button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#369;
  border:none;
  background:transparent;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  outline: 0;
}

.loading {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <ul id="tree2">
              <li>
                 <a href="#">TECH</a>
                 <ul>
                    <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                    <li>
                       Employees
                       <ul>
                          <li>
                             Reports
                             <ul>
                                <li>Report1 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label"> li text</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> </li>                            <li>Report2 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>                              <li>Report3 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                             </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Human Resources</li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                 XRP
                 <ul>
                    <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                    <li>
                       Employees
                       <ul>
                          <li>
                             Reports
                             <ul>
                                <li>Report1 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                                <li>Report2
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                                <li>Report3 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                             </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Human Resources</li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
```